# Drawing callouts on top of text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, presentations, callout

I'm putting together a presentation.  My presentation style, however, often involves bright red callouts to the most important points of the text, especially when said text consists of code samples or command line output.  Here's an example from a presentation I made in LibreOffice:

[image: Don't panic!]

**How can I do something similar with TikZ?**

Comment: Very related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204417/how-can-i-draw-arrows-within-a-listing-to-explain-positional-association https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110072/tikz-inside-lstlisting-inside-tikz

Comment: Welcome! **tikzmark** may be a good option. That's what I'd probably use.